# how to train machine learning algorithm with two target y1 and y2?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, artificial-intelligence

I want to train a machine learning algorithm with two target variables y1 and y2. One of the solutions that i think of is to train each target separately and then combine the predictions of the two models, but i do not know how to combine the two models. And even I do not know if this is a good idea .. any suggestions ? [description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Huct.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For a classification problem you may want to take a look into *multi-label classification*. For a regression problem it would be *multi-target regression*.

For a definitive advice you should provide more information.